# Possible to load multiple images with imager for lapply operations?

Tags: r

I am attempting to load multiple png images with imager in r, convert to data frame, and analyze the `x`, `y`, `cc`, and `value` columns accordingly. This is a sample code for what I am working with, and it appears to only load the first image from the list of files and repeats the process over that single first image. Is it possible to perform this over multiple images with imager? I like the format of the `x`, `y`, `cc`, and `value` columns. I eventually would like to write this out into multiple .csv files for each data frame. At minimum I will reduce to combine the lists and perform some aggregate operations. I have tried `readImage` but the output is a bit unclear.

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/Raw", pattern = "*.png", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
img.alter.merge <-lapply(files, function(x) {
  loadedimgs <- load.image(x)
  imgsdf <- as.data.frame(loadedimgs)
  write.csv(imgsdf, path = "C:/Users/Processed/imgsdf.csv")
})
```

Comment: You're writing all your files to the same file path. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I have also attempted the following code and it looks good, but not sure of the format as I am simply looking for a single data frame without any unnecessary list layers :                                                                                 img_list<-lapply(files,readPNG)
img_list<-lapply(img_list,as.data.frame.table)             img_list_final<-rbindlist(img_list)

Comment: hello dash2, how would you recommend writing multiple files to the same folder path? Thanks